# Spring Cloud Config with HOCON files

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, typesafe-config

I have configuration files which are in HOCON (`.conf`) format. I would like to use Spring Cloud Config to fetch them from a BitBucket repo, and send them to an application (which is NOT a Spring application) when it boots.

I am using the "Serving Plain Text" feature of Spring Cloud Config to fetch and serve a single HOCON file, which defines a particular environment. For example, the client application requests the `development.conf` environment configuration file, and by specifiying it's exact path in the BitBucket repo, say `myApp/development/master/development.conf`, the client is served that plaintext file.

However, as is usually desired, I would like base properties from the `base.conf` to be included in `development.conf` and have values overridden by the dev enviroment property values if there are common properties in both files.

Previously there was no config server, and so by simply writing the `include "base"` command at the top of the `development.conf` file, a HOCON parser (part of the TypeSafe library) in the client app requested the `base.conf` file (both files being in local directories), and did the overriding when necessary.

When including a Spring Config server, `development.conf` can be fetched in plain text as mentioned, but it is only (as before) at the client side that the application parses the `include "base"` command and then refetches the `base.conf` file. This makes the boot phase of the app very slow (probably) because fetching the additional files requires additional authorization on BitBucket.

Question: how to make it faster?

I have tried `spring.cloud.config.server.git.cloneOnStart: true`, but this has apparently no improvement (maybe I'm using it incorrectly?)

Should I consider converting the `.conf` format to `.properties` format, and using `spring.profiles.include: base` property at the top of the new `developement.properties` file?

Perhaps embed the Spring server in another Spring Boot application?

I like the property overriding and inclusion feature of Spring Cloud. I just don't know how to make it work with HOCON formatted files.

Comment: The format of the files doesn't have anything to do with it at this point. I'm a bit unclear as to how you are getting the files to the not spring app right now.

Comment: You can quickly spin up a Spring Cloud Config server and then you can curl a plaintext endpoint as they discuss [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__serving_plain_text.html)

Comment: I'm aware. I'm a maintainer of the project. You just haven't said how you are getting your files. Are you using curl?

Comment: The client application is a dropwizard project which is using a TypeSafe library (https://lightbend.github.io/config/). I pass in the plaintext url endpoint of the config server as a program argument when the app boots, and the Jersey http client (part of dropwizard) has all the feautures to resolve the url and call the endpoint. The actual plaintext HOCON files ae then parsed by the TypeSafe library.

Comment: I've got no idea. How slow is slow?

Comment: The current solution: less than a second to start, read in the config files, do overridding etc. 
Using Spring Cloud Config server: over a minute to fetch the configs from BitBucket.
Do you think the slowness is coming from multiple auth's against my BitBucket repo?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209785/discussion-between-rowan-and-spencergibb).